# Android: Root -> Give app permission -> Unroot? Does an app loose permission granted by su after unrooting the phone?

Tags: android, adb, android-permissions, root, superuser

App.apk programatcially runs the command: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("screenrecord", "--time-limit 5", "/sdcard/demo1.mp4")`

To do so, It requires permission, which also requires rooting the phone to give this app permissions.

The problem is rooting puts the phone at both malfunctioning and security risks.

**Note:** This app is not to be published, but used by one normal user.

**The question:**

Is It possible to:
1- Root the phone, then
2- Give the app this permission, then
3- Unroot the phone

**In other words:**
If an app is given full permission by the `root` user, does this app loose these permission after unrooting the phone ?

Comment: yes, It will lose permission as it is provided at the run time. Every time app starts it asks for SU permission to execute the above command.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please check the other question related to exit codes meaning ?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/64844158/13695921