# Where to lookup for the meaning "adb screencap" command's exit codes or how to get the meaning programatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, lookup, exit-code

```
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("screencap -p /storage/sdcard0/test3332.png");
        p.waitFor();
        String error = "error: " +  p.exitValue();
```

`p.exitValue()` is equal to `11`

**How to get the "meaning" or message from this exit code?**

If this should be available in the command's manual, then where to find this manual? Can someone post a link or a reference ?

Comment: are you sure that the exitValue is 11 and not 1?

Comment: Yes it's 11. Inspected also after debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message can be retrieved in this way:

```
int ch;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while((ch = p.getErrorStream().read()) != -1) {
    sb.append((char)ch);
}
String errorString = sb.toString();
Log.d("TAG", "Error is: " + errorString);
```